# Troubleshooting a yum update that breaks gnome

Tags: gnome, scientific-linux, troubleshooting

Recently `yum update` gave me about 130 packages to update (mostly connected with upgrading from GNOME 3.8 to 3.14 on Scientific Linux 7).  I installed the updates, which went fine, but after logging off, the computer hung.  Rebooting also hung around the initialization of gnome.  I booted into run level 3, used yum history undo to revert, and got the computer up and running again.

Whenever I have had this problem before, it has been video driver related, but this laptop uses the default drivers packaged with scientific Linux, and since I don't need to reinstall them for kernel updates, I don't see why I would need to now (and wouldn't know how).

My question is then in two parts.  One, is there a way to find out specifically which of the 130 updates is causing the crash by looking at logs?  If not is there a simple way to pick out packages, installing them one by one, to sort this out?  I don't know how to get to the bottom of the dependency tree, so that I am only installing a couple at a time.  Every time I tried to cherry pick one package, it had 20-30 dependencies and I didn't feel like trying all 130 to find the bottom by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trial and error to look for small sets of updates, I would make a script which starts by asking for the list of updated packages, and *cancels* that, then (in the script of course) step through the list and *cancel* any update which would produce more than a set threshold number of packages, and let yum prompt me to confirm the actual update:

- the output from yum can be processed with awk to obtain just the *list* of packages, e.g., you get text like this:

```
     libtasn1                           x86_64    4.8-1.fc23       updates    325 k
     parted                             x86_64    3.2-18.fc23      updates    534 k
     python-osbs-client                 noarch    0.20-1.fc23      updates    108 k
     rpmlint                            noarch    1.8-6.fc23       updates    192 k

    Transaction Summary
    ================================================================================
    Upgrade  41 Packages

    Total download size: 7.2 M
    Is this ok [y/N]:
```

which gives the number of packages affected (and the list).

- you can get yum to list the packages without a prompt by piping "n" to the process, e.g.,

  echo n | yum upgrade kernel

A script like that would take a couple of hours to write, but greatly simplifies the process.  (I've used this approach in trimming down unwanted packages).